# Copy OLE DB driver between computers

Tags: driver, oledb, act

We have some computers that don't have an OLE DB driver that some other computers rely on for a central shared spreadsheet to update - it's becoming quite limiting that only a few users can update the sheet when others need it to be up to date.

The driver is called 'ACT OLE DB Provider for Reporting 2.0'. I have googled online for it and can't find a download link anywhere so I think it must come with the program; however all computers involved are using the most up-to-date version of ACT despite only some having the driver.

How can I manually copy the driver from one computer to others?

Answer (score 0):

ACT! seems to be some sort of CRM Marketing service and the provider is part of their SDK. Just a short google gave me...

[How to Create an OLE DB 2.0 Connection in Act!](https://help.act.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024247834-How-to-Create-an-OLE-DB-2-0-Connection-in-Act-)

Which links to...

[How to download the Act! Software Development Kit](https://help.act.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024239874-How-to-download-the-Act-Software-Development-Kit-SDK-)

I may have the wrong thing entirely of course. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I'm afraid I tried that already and the driver's not in the SDK package as far as I can see.

Comment: Ah well. Worth a go. I'll leave the post here so others don't go for that as well.